# If Tali dies after being romanced, can you romance someone else?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I romanced Tali and locked it in in *ME3*, but she dies on Rannoch, so can I romance someone else in the game?

Answer (score 1):

**No.** Once a *ME3* romance is "locked in," Shepard loses romance dialogue options with all other characters.

And since it must be said: it's pretty low of Shepard to destroy his girlfriend's species, no? Wanting to be Shepard's rebound after that incident is a death wish.

Comment: I'm imagining a 3-game playthrough where everyone Shepard romances, dies, starting with Ashley on Virmire...

Comment: Black widow Shepard

Comment: @Izzy that's not possible, as the only way to romance Tali is if you did it in ME2 and continued it in ME3, which means Shepard's love interest didn't die in ME2

Comment: @yx. Ahhh, I didn't know that. I only played ME3 through once, and exploring my romance options isn't really big on my priorities. Can any other romance options die in ME3?

Comment: @Izzy ash but she can already die in me1.

Comment: @yx. I've got it! Male Shepard, romance Ash in ME1 - kill her at Virmire. Romance whoever in ME2 - get them killed in the last mission. Romance Kaiden in ME3 - kill him / get him killed later on.

Comment: @izzy yes, that works

Answer (score -3):

Yes in mass effects you always had a choice to remain faithful or not so i do not see why not..

Comment: I do not see why not is not an acceptable answer since there's nothing else to back it up

Comment: "There are no penalties in expressing or reaffirming interest in multiple former romance options. For example, a male Shepard can answer favorably towards both Liara and Tali'Zorah"

Comment: @DujeZubcic Interesting quote - what is your source? You can edit your answer to include it, but I think it may be answering a slightly different question. From the way I understand it, the OP wants to know if you can 'go steady' with another character *after your first partner dies*, not whether you can express in more than one at the beginning of the game (which is what I suspect that quote is about)